# Angular | Firebase - Retrieve data for specific user

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I need to retrieve and subscribe to events for a specific user. I need the key of the event as well in the view.

```
getEvents(uid) {
        this.db.object(`eventsGuestsLookup/${uid}`).valueChanges()
            .subscribe(e => {
                for (const k in e) {
                    if (e.hasOwnProperty(k)) {

                        this.eventsRef = this.db.object(`events/${k}`);
                        this.eventsRef.snapshotChanges().subscribe(action => {
                            console.log(k);
                            console.log(action.payload.val());

                            this.events = this.eventsRef.valueChanges();

                        });
                    }
                }
            })
    }
```

Right now I have a list of the events but `event.name` is not defined.

{{event.name}}

Answer (score 0):

If you are not setting a default value for events, it is **`undefined`** when the form appears for first time so you see that error  or you can use the safe navigation since the data returned is asynchronous.

```
<h1> {{event?.name}}</h1>
```